# Batch Looping A Model With Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, loops

I know of the `find_in_batches` method for ActiveRecord, but this doesn't allow me to set my `:order` or `:limit`.

I am trying to loop through my data, and for every 6 items I want to wrap them in a `<div`>.

I was trying to whole...

```
<%
i = 0
@media.each do |media|
%>
<% if i%6 %><div class="section"><% end %>
    [...]
<% if i%6 %></div><% end %>
<%
i += 1
end
%>
```

But I feel this isn't efficient the "Rails" way. Could I possibly split up my array into 4 different arrays of 6? I am trying to find the best approach to this and was hoping you guys could help.

In the end I need it to come out something like this:

```
<!--
  I have 24 items in my array, and I need to wrap every 6 inside a div.
-->
<div class="section">
   <div class="item"></div>
   <div class="item"></div>
   <div class="item"></div>
   <div class="item"></div>
   <div class="item"></div>
   <div class="item"></div>
</div>

<div class="section">
   <div class="item"></div>
   <div class="item"></div>
   <div class="item"></div>
   <div class="item"></div>
   <div class="item"></div>
   <div class="item"></div>
</div>

<div class="section">
   <div class="item"></div>
   <div class="item"></div>
   <div class="item"></div>
   <div class="item"></div>
   <div class="item"></div>
   <div class="item"></div>
</div>

<div class="section">
   <div class="item"></div>
   <div class="item"></div>
   <div class="item"></div>
   <div class="item"></div>
   <div class="item"></div>
   <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You want in_groups_of:

```
<% @items.in_groups_of(6) do |group| %>
    <div class="section">
        <% group.each do |item| %>
            <div class="item"></div>
        <% end %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: It's also probably good to do a <% unless item.nil? %> incase you don't have a perfect set of data. This is exactly what I needed, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could start optimizing by using `each_with_index` instead of `each`, and `<%=..%>` instead of the long `if`s.

```
<% @media.each_with_index do |media, i| %>
<%= (i % 6) ? '<div class="section">' : '' %>
    [...]
<%= (i % 6) ? '</div>' : '' %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Using that code it wraps a div around every item in the loop. Here is a link to a better example: http://gist.github.com/150498

Comment: I just translated it right off your code. Now that I understand what you want, I'd recommend something similar to Micheal's answer.

Answer (score 2):

One thing that would be cleaner:

```
<% while @media.size > 0 do %>
  <div>
  <%= @media.slice!(0,6).map{|m| m.to_html}.join('</br>')
  </div>
<%end%>
```

Answer (score 2):

To answer kind of a side part of your question: You should be able to use `find_in_batches` along with scopes (either named or anonymous) to set order and limit options.

Comment: I have a :featured scope, but I need to pull in a certain order and limit how many I want.

Comment: So you would create a scope for the order and limit that you want.

Answer (score 0):

The most "Rails" like way would be to use the content_tag helper and surround all data with divs, using a specific class for the 6th div.

```
<% @media.each_with_index do |m, i| %>
  <% content_tag(:div, :class => ( (i % 6==0 )? 'six' : 'other')) do %>
    <%= m %>
  <% end%>
<% end %>
```